# Google Sheets Function to Actively Check Cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've a function I'm using that checks the cell of the color and returns Yes/No in another column. However, after applying the function, and then changing the color of the cell afterwards the function isn't applied anymore.

For example the function is applied and returns "Yes", then if I change the color of the cell to white it doesn't return to "No". Is it possible to have the function to actively check the cell, or I just need to reapply the function each time the color of the cell changes?

```
function GetCellColorCode(input) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var cell = ss.getRange(input); 
  var result = cell.getBackground(); 

  var green = '#d9ead3';
  var white = '#ffffff';

  if (result == green) {
    return 'Yes';
  } else {    
    return 'No';
  }  

}
```

Answer (score 3):

- You want to refresh the custom formulas of `=GetCellColorCode(###)` in the cells when the background color is changed.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose to refresh the formulas using TextFinder and the OnChange event trigger.

### Usage:

#### 1. Sample script.

Please copy and paste the following script.

```
function onChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType === "FORMAT") {
    const formula = "=GetCellColorCode";  // Function name of your custom function.

    const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    const tempFormula = "=sampleFormula";
    sheet.createTextFinder("^\\" + formula).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(tempFormula);
    sheet.createTextFinder("^\\" + tempFormula).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(formula);
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, `=GetCellColorCode` is replaced to other name using TextFinder, and then, it is modified to `=GetCellColorCode`. By this, the custom formula are refreshed.
- When you directly run the function of `onChange` at the script editor, an error occurs, because this function uses the event object of OnChange event trigger. Please be careful this.

#### 2. Install OnChange event trigger.

[Please install the OnChange event trigger to the function of `onChange`.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually)

1. From the script editor, choose **Edit > Current project's triggers**.
2. Click **Add Trigger**.
3. Under **Choose which function to run**, select the name of function you want to trigger.

   - In this case, please select `onChange`.
4. Under **Select event source**, select **From spreadsheet**.
5. Under **Select event type**, select **On change**.
6. Click **Save**.

#### 3. Test run.

After above flow was done, please change the background color of the cell. By this, the OnChange event trigger is fired and the function `onChange` is run. Then, the custom formula of `GetCellColorCode` is refreshed.

In this script, even when the cell is copied and pasted, the OnChange vente trigger is not run. Please be careful this. In this case, please modify the background color.

### Note:

- In this answer, it supposes that your custom formula name is `GetCellColorCode`. So when you changed the function name, also please modify above script. Please be careful this.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change)
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, however I'm getting failed executions for `Exception: Range not found
    at GetCellColorCode(Code:4:17)` on `var cell = ss.getRange(input);`. It took me a bit to realize that code run in the editor fails as it doesn't actually retrieves the argument. The function works, but it's not triggering the OnChange event trigger.

Comment: @user3128376 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In this sample script, `=GetCellColorCode` of `=GetCellColorCode("A1")` is overwitten by `=GetCellColorCode`. So the arguments is not changed. Unfortunately, your situation cannot be replicated. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including the current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm your issue.