# Find Replace google spread sheet app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this very small issue and I was hoping someone could help me solve it.
This is the code.

```
 function textFinder() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();


var textFinder = range.createTextFinder('=');

var firstOccurrence = textFinder.findNext();


var numOccurrencesReplaced = firstOccurrence.replaceWith("=");
}
```

When the code runs I get
Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceWith' of null
textFinder  @ findReplace.gs:11

I am trying to find the = in a function that is in A1 B1 D1

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `I am trying to find the = in a function that is in A1 B1 D1` and your showing script, I cannot understand your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your question?

Comment: Hi my friend, thank you for your question. I'm trying to search the entire sheet for = and replace it with = to make the function refresh. I do know that the function lives in a1 and b1 and d1 but in future I don't know where the = will be so I'll have to scan the whole sheet. Does that help

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to refresh all functions in a sheet using Google Apps Script.

In the case of refreshing the functions on Google Spreadsheet using TextFinder, I thought that these samples are useful. [Ref1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56893480) [Ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300428) [Ref3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17341399) But, in this case, I'm worried that in order to refresh all functions in a sheet, it might be a bit difficult. So, in this answer, I would like to propose a sample script for refreshing all functions in a sheet using Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const refresh = (a, b) => sheet.createTextFinder(a).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(b);
  
  refresh("^=(.+)$", "==$1");
  refresh("^==(.+)$", "=$1");
}
```

- If you want to refresh all functions in all sheets of a Google Spreadsheet, please modify `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` to `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`.

#### References:

- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)
- Related threads

  - [Custom function won't refresh as inputs are changed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56893480)
  - [Google Sheets Function to Actively Check Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300428)
  - [Refresh data retrieved by a custom function in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17341399)