# How to refresh google spreadsheets by clicking a "button"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I tried writing an AppsScripts script to refresh sheet each time I press a button that the script is assigned to.

The only thing that must change each time is the cell with formula "=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1;20))"

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, I thought that these threads might be useful. "https://stackoverflow.com/q/56893480", "https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300428" But, in this case, the event object is used and a part of the formula is used. So, in this answer, I would like to introduce a sample script for refreshing the cells including the specific function `=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1;20))` by clicking a button on the Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. And, please assign the function name of `myFunction` to a button on the Spreadsheet. By this, when you click the button, the script is run.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const formula = '=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1;20))'; // This is from your question.

  const temp = formula.replace(/([=()])/g, "\\$1");
  const dummyFormula = "=sample";
  const obj = [
    { "from": `^${temp}|^${temp.replace(/;/g, ",")}`, "to": dummyFormula },
    { "from": `^\\${dummyFormula}`, "to": formula }
  ];
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  obj.forEach(({ from, to }) =>
    sheet.createTextFinder(from).matchFormulaText(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(to)
  );
}
```

- When this script is run, the cells including a formula of `=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1;20))` in the active sheet are refreshed.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for refreshing your provided formula of `=INDIRECT("A"&RANDBETWEEN(1;20))` on the active sheet. When you change the formula, this script might be required to be modified. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [createTextFinder(findText) of Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createTextFinder(String))